# Diffeomorphism Invariance of frobenius norm

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Consider $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian Manifold (compact).

We have a isometry $\phi:(M,\phi^*g) \to (M,g)$.

One thing I want to know is, how can I efficiently show that intrinsic quantities like $|\nabla\nabla f|^2$ and $(\Delta f)$ are invariant under the isometry.

I have showed $|\phi_* A_p|_{g}=|A_p|_{\phi^*g}$ for any vector field $A$ and similar version of equality for tensors.

Yet, I still have no idea to show my problem. Is it calculate everything out in local coordinate rly the only way to solve this problem?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Yeah you can work in coordinates. If something only depends on the metric tensor, then an isometry preserves it. For example, since $\text{div}(X) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_{x_j}(\sqrt{g}X^j)$, it follows that div is invariant under isometry. Same reasoning applies to $\text{grad}$ and $\Delta$. Given that we are on a Riemannian manifold though, practically everything depends only on the metric ...